# How to Pass JSON Object value From HTML Onclick function to JavaScript ? MVC

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, button, onclick

I am working on MVC trying to pass id on click button from HTML to JS my code where i am creating table in HTML is,

```
<tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="Survey in vm.AllSurveys">
                        <td>{{Survey.visitNumber}} </td>
                        <td>{{Survey.id}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button id="myButton" onclick="myFunction('{{Survey.id}}');">Home</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

On click function is like,

```
function myFunction(id) {
    console.log(id);
    location.href = "http://localhost/Test?visitId="+id;
}
```

I have data in this format,

```
[{VisitNumber: "Visit_U_1", id: "107"},... So on]
```

But i got this error in html onclick line,

```
Error: [$compile:nodomevents] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.9/$compile/nodomevents
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js:6:416
    at pre 
 <button id="myButton" onclick="myFunction('{{Survey.id}}');">
```

I tried solutions but did not get success
Hopes for your suggestions

Comment: change your button's `onclick` to `onclick="myFunction(Survey.id)"` ?

Comment: getting this error Uncaught ReferenceError: Survey is not defined

Comment: change your html with <button id="myButton" ng-click="myFunction(Survey.id);">Home</button>


angularjs controller : 
$scope.myFunction = function(id){console.log(id)};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) directive to pass data like below code

```
<button id="myButton" ng-click="myFunction(Survey.id);">Home</button>
```

Comment: It must by using it some way but not getting error it seems like it is not calling method

Comment: `myFunction` function must be in your angularjs controller, then it will call the method.